# WKWebView doesn't react to 503 error

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, webkit, wkwebview

I am loading an url request in my `WKWebView`.

Charles shows me `Response Code: 503 Error` which is fine, because it should be unavailable, but

```
webView(_:didFail:withError:) 
webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)
```

functions are never called.

What should I do to handle this error response? I think delegates are set up properly.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebKitViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var urlRequest: URLRequest?

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        if let urlRequest = urlRequest {
            webView?.load(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        //constraints
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinishProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        //not called while request gets 503 error
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        //not called while request gets 503 error
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** `func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)` is total blunder. Skip that one.

Answer (score 1):

For one of your methods you use `UIWebView` instead of `WKWebView`. Consider to add following methods:

```
func webView(WKWebView, didFail: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)
func webView(WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check the error

```
  optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
  decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, 
  decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
```

It will provide you with navigationResponse
And check if it is 503 or 401 or anything else and handle it accordingly.

Check this link to understand more
[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455643-webview)

Hope it helps !